# Ran .map on array and assigned it to a new Array, but it's showing 'nil' in every index except [0]

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm doing the Ruby course from The Odin Project and I've ran into this issue.

I'm still very new to Ruby.

The code below attempts to take in a string and encrypt it using a 'Caesar Cipher'. In this case, it is taking the string and shifting the characters in the string 5 values to the right. e.g. "A" becomes "F", "w" becomes "b".

First of all, here's what I think is wrong and can probably be done in a better way:

On line `5 decrypt = ascii.map...` -- This doesn't seem right. There has to be a better way to change all the value in `ascii` without having to assign it to a new variable. I **think** the problem here is that I'm assigning a variable another variable that points to an array.(?)

**My questions are:** is this causing `index[0]` in `decrypt` to be `[66, nil,...nil]`? and, what is the correct way/method to use on `ascii` to reassign their initial ascii values to the shifted ascii values?

```
1 def caesar_cipher(string, shift)
2 
3   ascii = string.chars.map(&:ord)
4   p ascii
5   decrypt =  ascii.map { |letter|
6     if letter.between?(65, 90)
7       letter += shift
8       if letter > 90
9         letter = (letter - 90) % 26 + 64
10       end 
11     elsif letter.between?(97, 122)
12       letter += shift
13       if letter > 122
14         letter = (letter - 122) % 26 + 96
15       end
16     end
17   }
18   
19   p decrypt
20 
21 end
22 
23 caesar_cipher("What a string!", 5)
24
25 #=> [[87, 104, 97, 116, 32, 97, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 33] 
   # result from `p ascii` in line 4

   [66, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
   # result from `p decrypt` in line 19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby `if` returns `nil` if the condition is not met.

Since you `map` to the result of `if`, you should consider to always return a value:

```
if letter > 90
  letter = (letter - 90) % 26 + 64
end
```

should be read as:

```
if letter > 90
  (letter - 90) % 26 + 64 # no need to assign letter again
else
  letter # return the value from all branshes
end
```

This should be done everywhere.

Comment: This helped! There was more missing from my code. I had to iterate through  `decrypt` as well and call `.join` and the end of the block. Thanks!